# Using Moment.js as a plugin inside main.js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I registered Moment.js as a plugin, like this:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import moment from 'moment'

moment.locale('pt_BR')

Vue.use({
  install (Vue) {
    Vue.prototype.$moment = moment
  }
})
```

Now, I need to use this in my `main.js` filters

```
import './plugins/moment'

Vue.filter('formatDate', value => {
  return this.$moment(value, 'YYYY-MM-DD').format('DD/MM/YYYY')
})
```

Buth this return an error:

> Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property '$moment' of
>   undefined"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you can not access `this` like in the `vue` components for filter methods.

[By Evan You](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/5998#issuecomment-311965292)

> This is intentional in 2.x. Filters should be pure functions and should not be dependent on this context. If you need this you should use a computed property or just a method e.g. $translate(foo)

I guess the best way is importing the `moment` on `main.js` like this:

```
import moment from 'moment'

Vue.filter('formatDate', value => {
  return moment(value, 'YYYY-MM-DD').format('DD/MM/YYYY')
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Vue.filter() creates a global filter before the Vue instance is created, a global filter does not have access to the Vue instance therefore you can not access this.$moment. If you need to access the vue instance, you'll need to register a local filter on components.

However, you could rectify this by directly referencing the module:

```
import moment from 'moment';

Vue.filter('formatDate', value => {
  moment(value, 'YYYY-MM-DD').format('DD/MM/YYYY')
});
```